# sparse symmetric matrix generation with diagonal elements non zero in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have to generate a sparse symmetric matrix of given dimension n*n, in which all diagonal elements are non-zero. And off-diagonal elements can expect possible k number of non-zero values. Mean if k = 3, and n = 4, we should have symmetric sparse matrix of size 4*4. And all diagonal elements are non-zero. For a first row, there can be 3 non zero values, all other are zero. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Since you've tagged `scipy` I assume you are intending to use `scipy.sparse`.    The diagonal part is easy (e.g. `sparse.diags`), but I don't follow the rest.  I'd suggest building a matrix with the `coo` format inputs (data, rows, cols arrays).  Present that, and then we can suggest improvements.

Comment: Thanks hpauji. I can generate sparse matrix with sparse using sps.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(5, 5)).toarray(). But my requirements is a) I need all non-diagonal elements to be non-zero. b) The matrix should be symmetric. c)No. of non-zero values should be less than given parameter value k